# Removing the entire background from a mathematical formula image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, png, ocr, handwriting-recognition

Consider the following image:

[image]

I would like to remove the entire background (everything that does not belong to the) to be left only with the integral. My purpose is to make it easier to get the integral in LaTeX from OCR.

Comment: Define remove?  What exactly do you want to remove.  Is it the background texture or part of the formula? If the background texture, what "color" do you want in the background or transparency?  Please be specific when asking questions.  Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have clarified what I thought was obvious: I want to remove everything that does not belong to the formula. To get the formula as LaTeX code, only the part of the image that belongs to the formula is needed.

Comment: you have not said what you want (color) in place of your background

Comment: You also did not specify a programming languange

Comment: that is _handwriting_. any OCR for handwriting would be robust enough to handle those faint lines on the paper. any processing will just make the data worse. stop doing the work for AI. AI can learn to handle this a lot better than any processing you can do.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristophRackwitz, for your comment. Maybe, you are right, but I was just trying the scientific method: experimenting to learn whether preprocessing an image helps or not OCR of mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?  Using Imagemagick, I do a division normalization followed by a thresholding.

Input:

[image]

```
convert image.png \( +clone -blur 99 \) +swap -compose divide -composite -negate -threshold 18% -negate result.png
```

[image]

Adjust the threshold as desired.

**ADDITION**

Add morphology to thicken the lines

```
convert image.png \( +clone -blur 99 \) +swap -compose divide -composite -negate -threshold 25% -negate -morphology erode diamond:1 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @fmw42! That is something like you did that I want. With a threshold of 25% one can get rid of all small lines (that does not belong to the formula). Can now we make the formula as been drawn by a thicker line?

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer